# iSCSI connected to AWS Gateway, but keep asking formatting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

All right, I am pretty newbie to network and storage things, but in my research, we need to use AWS S3 to backup data, sounds simple enough!

So I follow the "AWS storage gateway user guide (API version 2013-06-30).

Below are details I could provide based on my best knowledge:

1. Gateway-cached
2. Gateway on-premises, using VMware ESXi Hypervisor
3. About 300 Gb cache and 150 upload buffer

And

1. AWS gateway is deployed and activated
2. Cache storage and upload buffer configured on VM
3. A volume in Amazon S3 is created.

After all the above completed, I tried to use my Windows 8 iSCSI to connect to VM. It shows as a disk in folder, so I did a initial formatting. But after this, it asks for formatting again.

I followed the guide, but unfortunately it didn't work for me this time. Could anyone provide any insight on this issue? Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I don't understand how iSCSI works.

Quoted from Amazon Storage Gateway User Guide:

> Each of your storage volumes is exposed as an iSCSI target. Connect only one iSCSI initiator to each iSCSI target

Since I thought iSCSI target as a network shared drive, I let multiple machine connect to the iSCSI target, resulting keeping asking for formatting.